# random process modeling in signal processing

Tags: matlab, random, deterministic

i would like to understand one  thing and please  help me to clarify it,sometimes it is  necessary  to represent given data  by   sum of complex exponentials with additive  white noise,let us consider following model  using sinusoidal model

```
clear all;
A1=24;
A2=23;
A3=23;
A4=23;
A5=10;
 f1=11.01;
 f2=11.005;
 f3= 10;
 f4=10.9
 phi=2*pi*(rand(1,4)-0.5);
 t=0:0.01:2.93;
 k=1:1:294;
x=rand([1,length(t)]);
 y(k)=A1.*sin(2*pi*f1*t+phi(1))+A2.*cos(2*pi*f2*t+phi(2))+A3.*sin(2*pi*f3*t+phi(3))+A4.*cos(2*pi*f4*t+phi(4))+A5.*x;
 [pxx,f]=periodogram(y,[],[],100);
 plot(f,pxx)
```

there phases are distributed uniformly in range of [-pi pi],but my main question is  related following fact.to represent  data as  linear combination of complex exponentials with phases uniformly distributed in [-pi pi] interval, should we generate  these phases outside of  sampling or at each sampling process we should generate new list of phases?please help me to clarify this  things

Comment: what is a reason of downvoting

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I can understand the person who did it. In my opinion, this question is poorly phrased, contains both too little and too much information at the same time, and it's hard to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this line compile? `[pxx,f]=periodogram(y,[],[],100);` I am receiving an error.

Comment: why it is difficult?we have uniformly generated phases right?

Comment: please read question carefully maybe English is bad,but i am asking  should i generate  this phases uniformly at once or i should generate new set of phases at each iteration,what is unclear?

Comment: in simple languages code phi=2*pi*(rand(1,4)-0.5); should be outside of t vectorization or inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the my comment, I don't really understand what you're asking. *But*, I will answer this as if you had asked it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

The following is not good practice in MATLAB:

```
A1=24;
A2=23;
A3=23;
A4=23;
A5=10;
```

There are very few cases (if any), where you actually need such variable names. Instead, the following would be much better:

```
A = [24 23 23 23 10];
```

Now, if you want to use `A1`, you do `A(1)` instead.

These two lines:

```
t=0:0.01:2.93;
k=1:1:294;
```

They are of course the same size (1x294), but when you do it that way, it's easy to get it wrong. You will of course get errors later on if they're not the same size, so it's nice to make sure that you have it correct on the first try, thus using linspace might be a good idea. The following line will give you the same `t` as the line above. This way it's easier to be sure you have exactly 294 elements, not 293, 295 or 2940 (it is sometimes easy to miss).

```
t = linspace(0,2.93,294);
```

Not really important, but `k = 1:1:294` can be simplified to `k = 1:294`, as the default step size is 1.

The syntax `.*`, is used for element-wise operations. That is, if you want to multiply each element of a vector (or matrix) with the corresponding element in another one. Using it when multiplying vectors with scalars is therefore unnecessary, `*` is enough.

Again, not an important point, but `x=rand([1,length(t)]);` is simpler written `x=rand(1, length(t));` (without brackets).

You don't need the index `k` in `y(k) = ...`, as k is continuous, starting at 1, with increments of 1. This is the default behavior in MATLAB, thus `y = ...` is enough. If, however, you only wanted to fill in every other number between 1 and 100, you could do `y(1:2:100)`.

This is far from perfect, but in my opinion big step in the right direction:

```
A = [24 23 23 23 10];
f = [11.01 11.005 10 10.9];   % You might want to use , as a separator here
phi = 2*pi*(rand(1,4)-0.5);
t = linspace(0,2.93,294);
x = rand(1, length(t));

w = 2*pi*f;   % For simplicity
y = A(1)*sin(w(1)*t+phi(1)) + A(2)*cos(w(2)*t+phi(2)) + ...
    A(3)*sin(w(3)*t+phi(3)) + A(4)*cos(w(4)*t+phi(4))+A(5)*x;
```

Another option would be:

```
z = [sin(w(1)*t+phi(1)); cos(w(2)*t+phi(2)); sin(w(3)*t+phi(3)); ...
    cos(w(4)*t+phi(4)); x];
y = A.*z;
```

This will give you the same `y` as the first one. Having the same `w`, `t` and `phi` as above, the following will also give you the same results:

```
c = bsxfun(@times,w,t') + kron(phi,ones(294,1));
y = sum(bsxfun(@times,A,[sin(c(:,1)), cos(c(:,2)), sin(c(:,3)), cos(c(:,4)), x']),2)';
```

I hope something in here might help you some in your further work. And maybe I actually answered your question. =)

Comment: +1 for giving such a good quality answer to a not-so-good-quality question.

Comment: @Robert P thanks for matlab syntax,it is more professional of course,but that is not my question,look please i have random phases  yes?generally there exist models which are sinusoidal  with phases uniformly distributed  right?i am asking to get this model correctly,should i generate they at once and  insert into model or at each iteration i should generate new sample?is it so unclear?in which language should i talk? :(

Comment: in other word,if i took  loop instead of vectorization,should i generate this random sample of phases at each iteration of loop?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but I think vectorization would be the best approach. I don't understand this well enough to give you a better answer than that I'm afraid.

Comment: let us continue it to chat ok?